# Infinite complex nested radical and it's complex conjugate.

Tags: complex-numbers, nested-radicals

Today I want to play with $i$ the imaginary unit I have this :
$$\overline{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{1+i^2\sqrt{1+i^3\sqrt{1+i^4\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}$$

Main remarks we have :

$$\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{1+i^2}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^2}}}=1$$
$$\overline{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{1+i^2\sqrt{1+i^3}}}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^3}}}}$$

$$\overline{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{1+i^2\sqrt{1+i^3\sqrt{1+i^4}}}}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^4}}}}}$$

$$\overline{\sqrt{1+i\sqrt{1+i^2\sqrt{1+i^3\sqrt{1+i^4\sqrt{1+i^5}}}}}}=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^4}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^5}}}}}}$$

### And so on...

### My question :

What happend in the infinite case ?

Have we a closed form for this special nested radical ?

Edit : It was in fact the complex conjugate.

Thanks a lot for sharing your time and knowledge .

Comment: Why do you think these hold? The third equality, that $\sqrt{1 + i \sqrt{1 + i^2 \sqrt{1 + i^3}}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{i^2} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{i^3}}}}$, already seems false. If we let $x$ be the left side, and $y$ the right side, then $((x^2 - 1)^2 + 1)^2 = 1-i$, while $((y^2 - 1)^2 + 1)^2 = 1+i$, so they cannot be equal. Beyond that issue, your expressions just aren't well-defined, since the square root of a complex number can have two values, so with each iterated root you have twice as many possible values.

Comment: @user125932 . Thanks a lot because I don't see on Wolfram alpha my fault . It's the complex conjugate in fact.

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment on this. Well first and foremost, I see that you're doing a lot of radicals of this form & also much trivially we can get; 
$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}\sqrt{x^{4}+\sqrt{x^{6}+\sqrt{x^{8}+\sqrt{x^{10}+\sqrt{x^{12}+...}}}}}$$

So In a way;

$$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^3}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{i^4}\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=\frac{1}{i^{2}}\sqrt{i^{4}+\sqrt{i^{6}+\sqrt{i^{8}+\sqrt{i^{10}+\sqrt{i^{12}+...}}}}}$$
$$=-1$$

One can make a sense out of this, and I still don't personally like nested imaginary units myself. But the solution above is most likely wrong, because the identity claimed at first is by my observation only applicable for positive real quantities.